# Constrained minimization using fmincon

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints

I wanted to solve a constrained minimization problem using `fmincon`. But the constraints are defined in terms of a function like `f(x_0)<a`, where `x_0` is a solution to the problem. Is it possible?

On the docs, the example only include this `x_0<a` form.

Code:

```
f_obj = @(x)var_zcors(x,t_cw);
opt_theta = fminbnd(f_obj,0,360);
```

Now, x should constrained such that `f_constraint(x)< a`.

Update(From answer by @Phil Goddard):

```
f_obj = @(x)var_zcors(x,t_cw);
f_nl = @(x)deal(f_constraint(x)-a,[]);
x0 = 180; % or whatever is appropriate
opt_theta = fmincon(f_obj,x0,[],[],[],[],0,360,f_nl);
```

Say in the above code `f_constraint` returns a vector `[x_min y_max]` instead of a scalar. And I want to specify the following constraints:

```
x_min>b
y_max<a
```

What is a possible way to achieve that?

Comment: Your have a non-linear constraint and need to use the 9th input to [fmincon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html).  See the doc for details and a usage example.

Comment: @PhilGoddard Sorry couldn't find it. Are you referring to this one? http://in.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#busqazq-1

Comment: Yes, as per the link in my comment.

Comment: @PhilGoddard Thanks, I went through it again. Not sure that would do it, can you show the code for my question to better explain . In my question, `f_constraint` is matlab function.

Answer (score 6):

You have a nonlinear constraint and hence need to use the nonlinear constraint input to `fmincon`.  That is,

```
f_obj = @(x)var_zcors(x,t_cw);
f_nl = @(x)deal(f_constraint(x)-a,[]);
x0 = 180; % or whatever is appropriate
opt_theta = fmincon(f_obj,x0,[],[],[],[],0,360,f_nl);
```

If you have multiple (non-linear) constraints, then as per the examples in the doc, you write a function to return a vector of constraints.  In your case you want to write a function *in a separate* file like the following:

```
function [c,ceq] = my_nonlinear_constraints(x,ab)

% define the non-linear inequality constraints
% (This assumes that ab is a 2 element vector containing your a and b
% variables.)
[x_min,y_max] = f_constraint(x);
c = nan(2,1);
c(1) = -x_min+ab(2); % this is x_min>b
c(2) = y_max-ab(1);  % this is y_max<a

% There are no non-linear equality constraints, but this is required
ceq = [];
```

Then, to perform the optimization, you want

```
% Variables a and b must be defined prior to this.
f_obj = @(x)var_zcors(x,t_cw);
f_nl = @(x)my_nonlinear_constraints(x,[a b]);
x0 = 180; % or whatever is appropriate
opt_theta = fmincon(f_obj,x0,[],[],[],[],0,360,f_nl);
```

Comment: thanks! In  `f_nl = @(x)deal(f_constraint(x)-a,[]);` why did you subtract `a`. Also, to be sure I understand, it will evaluate f_nl for each solution(`x_0`), what should f_nl return, for it to tell `fmincon` that the constraint is not satisfied for `x_0`.

Comment: As per the doc, `a` is subtracted because the nonlinear constraint must be specified in the form `constraint <= 0`, that is `0` must be on the right-hand-side of the inequality.  Also `f_nl` must return 2 outputs: the first must be the nonlinear inequality constraints, and the second must be the nonlinear equality constraint (of which you don't have any, and hence the above code returns an empty matrix `[]`.

Comment: thanks for the lucid explantation! Can you please also tell to accomplish the same for two such constraints instead of only one as the answer has right now.